# How to perform a complex search using ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, search, activerecord

I have a search form with several fields and it currently works. I have written the search action in the following way:

```
conditions = {}
conditions[:x] = params[:x] unless params[:x].blank?
conditions[:y] = params[:y] unless params[:y].blank?
conditions[:z] = params[:z] unless params[:z].blank?
etc.
@results = Material.where(conditions)
```

And this is fine. But now I want to add a condition that says essentially "where the level is less than or equal to params[:level], which would look like this in my head:

```
conditions[:level] <= params[:level] ...
```

But this doesn't work because it seems you can only add hashes using this syntax. So my question is how I would add such a condition to the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add this to your existing `conditions` hash. The hash `key: value` arguments to `where` can *only* produce `where key = value`, not `key <= value`.

Use a parameterized string and an additional `where`:

```
@results = Material.where(conditions).where("level <= ?", params[:level])
```

Comment: I thought this might be the case. Thanks for the help!